# Embargo Free SVN or Git

Tags: git, subversion

Some git hosts such as github and gitlab are posing embargos for people of some countries based on US trade laws. In particular, Iran and Syria are affected by such embargo.

As a consequence I'm having difficulty to collaborate with my Iranian colleagues.

Are there any git equivalent or some svn provider that does not empose such embargos. Preferentially some in Europe or in a more or less politically neutral country?

Comment: Set up a server and run `gitlab-ce` on your own infrastructure?